# How to pass ArrayList to the constructor?

Tags: java, oop

I'm working in a project class and want to know how to pass an ArrayList to the constructor.

For example, I have an `Item` class with a child Class named `CDRom` (inheritance), then `CDRom` needs to have one or more authors so I thought that every object from `CDRom` will have to have their own ArrayList inside the object. But this is possible? And how?

At the moment I have this:

```
public CDRom(int codi, double preu, String titul, Date dataPublicacion, List<String> autors, int stock) {
    super(codi, preu, titul, dataPublicacion, autors);
    this.stock = stock;
}

public static boolean createCdrom() {
    boolean valid = true;
    
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println(dtf.format(localDate)); 
    
    String[] arr = {"autor1","autor2","autor3"};
    
    //CDRom cdrom = new CDRom(count++, 34.99, "The Beattles", dtf.format(localDate), Arrays.asList("asd1","asd2"),50);
    CDRom cdrom = new CDRom(count++, 34.99, "The Beattles", dtf.format(localDate), Arrays.asList("asdd","asd"), 50);
    return valid;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're passing the ArrayList with authors to your superclass (`Item`), so it's already stored there for each `CDRom` object I suspect.

Comment: Please post code as code-formatted text , since we can't copy an image of code into our IDE's and test it.

Comment: im sill a little confused, what do you mean by "But this is possible? And how?"

Comment: @joshau I mean if I can store an array of authors in an object, so every object will have his own list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the constructor arguments order

```
public CDRom(int codi, double preu, String titul, Date datePublicacion, ArrayList<String> autors, int stock){
```

But you are passing arguments in wrong order, and also you are trying to pass something invalid  in the place of `ArrayList`

```
CDRom cdrom = new CDRom(count++, 34.99, "The Beattles", dtf.format(localDate), 50, autors[]{"asdd", "asd"});
```

Follow the order

```
CDRom cdrom = new CDRom(count++, 34.99, "The Beattles", dtf.format(localDate), Arrays.asList("asdd","asd"), 50);
```

**Note** Always update the code in the post not the image

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool , but tried the Array.asList and then get an error with the constuctor "The constructor CDRom(int, double, String, String, List<String>, int) is undefined"

Comment: change this `ArrayList<String>` to `List<String>` in constructor , it clearly says you are passing `List` but expected is `ArrayList` @ToniTJK